# Validation context not checking Validation Attributes

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I'm running into a weird scenario and I'm hoping it's a chair and keyboard kind of error.

I can't seem to get the validation context to check any other validation attribute.

here is my poco:

```
  public class TestMe
  {
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(1,40)]
    public int Count { get; set; }

  }
```

and I am running

```
  var t = new TestMe();
  t.Count = 0;
  var context = new ValidationContext(t, null, null);
  var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
  var result = Validator.TryValidateObject(t, context, validationResults);
```

this seems to return true with no errors.
it only seems to check the `RequiredAttribute`. I tried creating a new attribute to check to see if IsValid is getting called and to my disappointment neither of the IsValid functions were executed. I overrode the `RequiredAttribute` and that one DOES seem to be getting called.

Does anyone know what the heck I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = Validator.TryValidateObject(t, context, validationResults, true);
```

You must make use of the `validateAllProperties` parameter in `TryValidateObject`. Set it to `true`. that's it then range validator should work as expected.

hope this helped!

Comment: I actually figured this out just 2 mins ago. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to allow the Validator.TryValidateObject() to run. If you are debugging and have a breakpoint on/before the Validator you will not see results.